Google sheets - Calculating shift hours
The goal of this  spreadsheet is to calculate total hours worked and out of that figure out how many hours has been in the day shift (from 6:00 to 22:00) and how many hours has been in the night shift (from 22:00 to 6:00).
The start and end hours are arbitrary and the duration is also arbitrary, but no more than 24 hours.
Now, the question is if there is any better way of solving this. I went and done each and every condition to come up with the IFS formula.
The formula works, but I am sure that there is a better way.
Also, I want to share this to others that wind up here.
Now, the main column is the Night shift (E) since it has the formula I am questioning right now.
The whole formula:
=IFS(NOT(ISNUMBER(G3)),"",AND(D3>C3,D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),C3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0)),0,AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),NOT(ISBLANK(C3)),D3=C3),0,C3>D3,IF(D3>TIME(6,0,0),TIMETOINTH(TIME(6,0,0),IF(C3>TIME(22,0,0),C3,TIME(22,0,0))),TIMETOINTH(D3,IF(C3>TIME(22,0,0),C3,TIME(22,0,0)))),AND(D3<=TIME(6,0,0),D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),C3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),TIMETOINTH(D3,TIME(22,0,0)),AND(D3>=TIME(22,0,0),D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),C3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),TIMETOINTH(D3,TIME(22,0,0)),AND(C3<=TIME(6,0,0),C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),TIMETOINTH(TIME(6,0,0),C3),AND(C3>=TIME(22,0,0),C3>TIME(6,0,0),D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),TIMETOINTH(TIME(6,0,0),C3))

The same formula with my comments for easier read:
=IFS(
// 1st condition to check if there is something to calculate
NOT(ISNUMBER(G3)),"",
// 2nd condition
AND(
D3>C3,
D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),
D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),
C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),
C3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0)
),
0, // result for night shift hours
// 3rd condition
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),NOT(ISBLANK(C3)),D3=C3
),
0, // result
// 4th condition
C3>D3,
IF(
D3>TIME(6,0,0),
TIMETOINTH(TIME(6,0,0),IF(C3>TIME(22,0,0),C3,TIME(22,0,0))), // result 4.1
TIMETOINTH(D3,IF(C3>TIME(22,0,0),C3,TIME(22,0,0)))), // result 4.2
// fifth condition, 4 subconditions
// 5.1
AND(
D3<=TIME(6,0,0),
D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),
C3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),
C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),
TIMETOINTH(D3,TIME(22,0,0)), // 5.1 result
AND(
D3>=TIME(22,0,0),
D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),
C3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),
C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),
TIMETOINTH(D3,TIME(22,0,0)), // 5.2 result
AND(
C3<=TIME(6,0,0),
C3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0),
D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),
D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),
TIMETOINTH(TIME(6,0,0),C3), // 5.3 result
AND(
C3>=TIME(22,0,0),
C3>TIME(6,0,0),
D3+TIME(0,1,0)>TIME(6,0,0),
D3-TIME(0,1,0)<TIME(22,0,0)),
TIMETOINTH(TIME(6,0,0),C3)) //5.4 result

The TIMETOINTH is a named function that translates to =INT(TEXT(end_hour-start_hour,"h")) where both variables must be in the TIME(0,0,0) format.
The inputs are the month/year in the H1 (month/year) and the hours in the C and D columns (6:00 | 06:00 | 23:00).
Thank you.

Yes, I have seen that and the official demo, but if you look closely, it calculates the duration in total, it does not split it as total=night+day. Or my brain is just melted from my formula that I am not seeing the answer (edit) ->> Yes, it was melted, since I did not even see the "Evening" Sheet in the official docs... Oh god...

in that demo sheet there are two tabs. one for day shift one for evening shift. each tab calculates the part not the total. anyway, what is your question here? is your IFS formula working correctly (I was not able to reproduce it - so would be nice if you could share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result) or are you seeking optimization of formula / array variant?

Well, yes, optimization and explanation of the better answer, and even a feedback if the sheet is simple enough for people to use it. I did share the sheet, but not in correct format, editing the link now.

based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78536206/5632629
F3:
=INDEX(IF(D3:D33="",,LET(x, 86400, b, C3:C33, c, D3:D33, 
 bb, b*x, cc, c*x, cd, cc+((c<b)*x), 
 IF((bb>("22:00"*x))*(cd>cc)*(cc>("06:00"*x)), 
   MAP(cc, LAMBDA(cc, MIN(cc-("06:00"*x), (("22:00"-"06:00")*x)))), 
   MAP(BYROW(cd, LAMBDA(cd, MIN(cd, ("22:00"*x)))), 
       BYROW(bb, LAMBDA(bb, MAX(bb, ("06:00"*x)))), 
       LAMBDA(x, y, MAX(x-y, 0)))))/60^2))


G3:
=INDEX(LET(s, 86400, c, C3:C33, d, D3:D33, 
 IF((c="")+(d=""),,((IF(d<c, 1)+d)*s-c*s)/60^2)))


E3:
=INDEX(LET(g, G3:G33, f, F3:F33, IF(g<>"", g-f, )))



Thank you so much for taking your time to correct my formula. It even extends into minutes, which was my next iteration of my formula. Thank you again.
